# Unused foreach loop performance impact?

Tags: php, performance, loops, foreach

I've got a question regarding foreach loops with respects to a situational XML parser that I'm working on using DOM (essentially, it looks for some hard-coded values within the XML). Does anyone know the system performance impact of a foreach loop that doesn't actually wind up being called?

Just for reference, I'm looking at at least two discrete types of XML file each of which has a number of loops in and of itself, and I'd like to use the same parsing file to look at each.

So, for instance, it would look at an  tree with one function, and then a  tree with another. What would be the outcome of running a .php file that holds the information to respond to both but simply chooses one or the other appropriately?

For instance, were I to call foreach($foo as $bar), but there is no $bar, then what would happen to the code that would run in the foreach loop? I'm pretty sure it would output an error (though this would be suppressed on the reporting side), but would PHP's performance suffer as it parses the code inside it?

I may be somewhat unclear; I've probably used the wrong terminology somewhere, so I'll make a summary:

Do foreach loops involving associative arrays that don't exist have a performance impact.

For reference, I want to do something similar to the example under Listing 2 on this page: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-xmldomphp/

Were there no books in the XML file fed into the "Listing 2" example, would there be a major problem, or would PHP simply move on nicely (a non-fatal error counts as nicely for my purposes), or would there be a performance hit?

Comment: _“were I to call foreach($foo as $bar), but there is no $bar”_ – that makes no sense. `$bar` comes into life only _because_ the foreach loop is operating over data. You probably _meant_ what if `$foo` is an empty array.

Comment: And as always: What you are being concerned about here is “micro optimization”, that in 99.999…99 percent of all real uses cases will not make any relevant difference at all.

Comment: Implement it both ways, measure the diffence, and choose the approach that fits your performance requirements.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear that I'll actually be working with associative arrays. I'm not sure what difference that makes, if any, but I've got 20/30 case-based foreach loops in there, that is "foreach object as object => requirement". As far as doing manual testing, my main concern is that I don't really know what my end performance requirements may be, nor am I experienced enough to know that my testing is truly rigorous. I'm hoping to develop something that others might use on their own servers, which could be wildly different environments.

Comment: If you don't have stated performance requirements, then performance may be whatever is best given other constraints.  For example, usually increasing performance decreases maintainability, and it may be undesirable (absent requirements) to decrease maintainability for a marginal performance improvement.

Comment: It can't be more than what... 4 processor instructions to figure out that the looped array is empty and move on.  Since your processor probably only handles billions of operations per second.  You can quickly see that 30 lost instances of nanoseconds is going to bog your system to its knees.  (Finally, if you don't know how loops work and what is/isn't an error?!! write some simple tests and learn your chosen language!)

Comment: I know enough to know that something like this in Javascript would essentially be a carnal sin; I'm just asking how PHP handles a foreach that it doesn't have any of the elements of.

Comment: @KyleWilley There is **nothing wrong** with a for loop which is skipped.  However, **language errors** and **exceptions** are often very expensive.  Here's what PHP doc has to say about `foreach`: *foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable. foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable.* see: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the situation is that it would never actually make inside of the `foreach()` loop for execution purposes.

However, the actual bytes which the code takes up in terms of disk space will be loaded into memory so that it can be processed if you successfully enter the `foreach()`

I personally develop in an environment where ALL errors show up so that I can ensure my code is rock-solid for production.

If I am expecting an array or object then I generally implement this:

```
// check for the existence of $foo and make sure it is loop-able
// being loop-able means $foo is either and array or object and contains at least one item/element
if((is_array($foo) || is_object($foo)) && count($foo) > 0)
{
    foreach($foo as $bar)
    {
    }
}
```

Overall, your question/concern is in line with micro-optimization and when you micro-optimize, nobody wins. Just make sure your code is easily understandable for future developers and re-factor it when deemed necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand this; are we checking to make sure that there's at least one $foo array, or should we be checking to see if there's a $bar item?

Comment: Pseudo code: `if ($foo is an array with at least one element) then foreach ($foo as $bar) { }`

Comment: Yes, make sure that `$foo` has at least one item in it before trying to loop through it, this is merely to avoid errors. If you turn off error reporting then you can avoid seeing errors completely but this is absolutely not recommended when developing code.

Comment: Use this code to dissect arrays/objects as you learn PHP: `echo '<div style="background-color:white; padding:15px;"><pre>'.print_r($foo, true).'</pre></div>';`

Comment: Ah, I see it now. It's amazing what breakfast (and an explanation) does for my understanding of code. Plus I need to stop thinking of arrays like an English teacher. So then if I wanted to check recursively down objects I could just define the array; for instance, if I had a <requirement>3</requirement> element (which is entirely arbitrary), I could have something like the following:

Comment: `$requirement = $object->getElementsByTagName("requirement")`; then `if((is_array($requirement) || is_object($requirement)) && count($requirement) > 0))`. Note that my goal here is to search with a specific $object, rather than within the whole document.

Comment: It seems a real waste to care what the `count()` is, at least from a read of the PHP docs.

Comment: @ebyrob If you loop an empty array then an error/notice is thrown. So if you turn off error display in development then I guess that is your call. Care to tell me what section of the docs I should brush up on?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Ouch really?  Someone should update the docs about that.  Note: I'm not saying you should be brushing up on the docs, so much as they should be brushing up on you ;-)  Tell me how far into this page you get before the actual empty behavior is obvious to you: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: No sweat man, I didn't take it personally, I just wanted to see if I could eliminate the "unnecessary" code from my practice to make life easier =). Always develop with all errors/notices and you will learn countless things. Also, I see zero mention of handling empty arrays/objects unless it is buried in the comments somewhere.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `Always develop with all errors/notices...` I live by this and for more reason than one.  Even beyond that tracing is my friend.  Of course I'm a C/C++/C#/SQL developer not really PHP, I just like to learn a bit now and then because of SQL and web tech crossover.  So many people with SQL issues here on SO use PHP.   Wait Wait... you shouldn't be brushing up *on* the docs, you should be brushing *up* the docs :-)

Comment: @ebyrob PHP and MySQL are zero-barrier technologies so you get to see people who barely know to use `<?php` to start their script run head-first into tutorials outside their league. I think that people are more willing to properly learn paid-for technologies before posting on SO but that's just my 2-cents.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Ah, so you think I'm after low-hanging fruit...  And you're the one with monkey in your nick ;-p  Maybe it shows my incompetence but I learn an awful lot from trying to write queries to answer crazy "can MySQL do this" questions.  (half mingled with PHP of course)

Comment: @ebyrob My bad, the comment wasn't directed at you, I was just piggy-backing your `So many people with SQL issues here on SO use PHP` statement